# Why some apps don't hold up the terminal after running from there

Tags: terminal, process

Often when I start an app from terminal, it starts and holds up the terminal so if I press `Ctrl+C`, the app will quit e.g.
 `[johndoe@localhost ~] gedit`
However, I notice some programs just start independently albeit run from terminal like `atom` and `code` (Visual Studio Code). Why is that? How does it work?

Comment: You are conflating _terminal_ and _shell_.  They do not hold up the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

They start in the background. To be more precise, they fork another process that continues to run, while the process started by the shell terminates.

If you are looking for details on how this is done, look for "daemonize".

**Edit**

As @JdeBP pointed out, dæmonization involves more than just a fork and exit. It usually involved closing all files or at least 0-2, another fork, detaching from the shell process group and so on. The programs you mentioned may or may no do this.

Comment: That second paragraph promotes a misconception that dæmonization is the same as running with a controlling terminal but not "owned" by a shell as one of its jobs.  It is not, and looking up dæmonization will serve to confuse with faulty ideas rather than edify.  fork and wait and how (job control) shells use them are what one needs to understand here.